# having trouble referencing directory structure

Tags: php, jquery, authentication, directory, structure

I have a directory structure:

```
/Users/Eamon/Sites:
  -js
    application.js
  -reqscripts
    jquery.js
  -templates
    login_success.php
    logout.php 
checklogin.php
checkreglogin.php
index.php
```

I am setting up a simple login system. Upon login, I get redirected to "checklogin.php", and a blank page appears. I think I am doing something wrong (in a few places...probabaly) with regards to referencing the directory structure.

application.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#login").submit(function(e) {  
        e.preventDefault();
        $.post('../checklogin.php', $(this).serialize(), function(){
            $("#showuser").load("../templates/login_success.php");
            $("#login").remove();
            $("#register").remove();
        });
    });

    $("#register").submit(function(e) {  
        e.preventDefault();
        $.post('../checkreglogin.php', $(this).serialize(), function(){
            $("#showuser").load("../templates/login_success.php");
            $("#login").remove();
            $("#register").remove();
        });
    });
});
```

Above, I reference the directory structure in the "$.post" call - as well as from within the post call's function.

login_success.php

```
<?php
session_start();

if($_SESSION['username'] === null){
    header("location:index.php");
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1>Login Successful</h1>
<h2>Username: <? echo $_SESSION['username']?></h2>
<a href = "logout.php">Log out</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Referenced dir structure in "header" and the html link.

logout.php

```
<?php
session_start();
session_destroy();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
You have been logged out.
<a href = "../index.php">Log in</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Dir structure referenced in html link.

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>it IT</title>
<script src="reqscripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/application.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="login" method="post" action="checklogin.php">
    <h1>Member Login</h1>
    <p>Username:<input name="myusername" type="text" id="myusername"></p>
    <p>Password:<input name="mypassword" type="password" id="mypassword"></p>
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login">
</form>
<form name="register" method="post" action="checkreglogin.php">
    <h1>Member Registration</h1>
    <p>Username:<input name="rmyusername" type="text" id="rmyusername"></p>
    <p>Password:<input name="rmypassword" type="password" id="rmypassword"></p>
    <p>Email:<input name="myemail" type="text" id="myemail"></p>
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Register">
</form>
<div id="showuser"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

jquery.js, and application.js are referenced in the "head" section. The form's action tags also reference the dir structure.

All these places I have pointed out need to be looked at - Anywhere I reference the dir structure.

**UPDATE**

Added this to index.php head:

```
<script language="text/javascript">
    var baseDir = "<? echo BASEDIR ?>";
</script>
```

In application.js, changed this:

```
$.post('../checklogin.php', $(this).serialize(), function(){
```

to this:

```
$.post(baseDir+"/checklogin.php", $(this).serialize(), function(){
```

and this:

```
$("#showuser").load("../templates/login_success.php");
```

to this:

```
$("#showuser").load(baseDir+"/templates/login_success.php");
```

Still getting the same result...

**UPDATE**

Changed:

```
var baseDir = "<? echo BASEDIR ?>";
```

to:

```
var baseDir = "<? echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] ?>";
```

I couldn't find any documentation on "BASEDIR" so I figured it was depreciated.

Still no luck...

**Just to be clear, if I put all the files in the same directory folder...everything works fine...**

Comment: First of all, remove all double dots `..`. Relative paths do not behave like you think from the browsers perspective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The javascript using .. `$("#showuser").load("../templates/login_success.php");` will not work because it is being loaded into the index.php page. Which means the javascript "does not know" that it is in the js directory.

You should remove the relative paths `../` and use paths relative to the base dir:

```
$.ajax({url: baseDir + "/session.php", success: function(data) {
You will need to set the baseDir Javascript variable in Top.php:

<script language="text/javascript">
    var baseDir = "<?php echo BASEDIR; ?>";
</script>
```

Found the basedir answer here: [Linking javascript BASEDIR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2716405/linking-javascript-basedir)

Also the forms do not have the id tag that the jQuery functions are looking for, add those:

```
<form id="login" name="login" method="post" action="checklogin.php">

<form id="register" name="register" method="post" action="checkreglogin.php">
```

Comment: ...tried it - didnt work...ill post what i did above in an update.

Comment: how about this line: $("#showuser").load("../templates/login_success.php");??

Comment: @ewizard On another look your functions are not being executed because they are looking for a form with ID="login" the forms only have a name attribute. You need to add the id="login" to your forms

Comment: i have a different problem now...see this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17099837/nothing-happens-after-check-login-script-php-jquery