# nothing happens after check login script php jquery

Tags: php, jquery, authentication, firebug

I am trying to right a simple login script. When I execute the "checklogin.php" script (upon being called by the login form) - nothing happens. I stay on index.php, and I still see the form (which should have been removed by some jquery). If I open firebug I see this:

```
POST http://localhost/~Eamon/checklogin.php 200 OK 2ms  jquery.js (line 8724)
GET http://localhost/~Eamon/templates/login_success.php 302 Found 1ms   jquery.js (line 8724)
GET http://localhost/~Eamon/index.php 200 OK 1ms    
GET http://localhost/~Eamon/reqscripts/jquery.js?_=1371173056318 200 OK 1ms jquery.js (line 8724)
GET http://localhost/~Eamon/js/application.js?_=1371173056319 200 OK 0
```

There aren't any errors - but I'm wondering if all those "GET" requests are correct. Should any of them be "POST"?

Here is my code:

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>it IT</title>
<script src="reqscripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/application.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="login" method="post" action="checklogin.php">
    <h1>Member Login</h1>
    <p>Username:<input name="myusername" type="text" id="myusername"></p>
    <p>Password:<input name="mypassword" type="password" id="mypassword"></p>
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

checklogin.php

```
<?php

session_start();

$host="localhost"; // Host name
$username="root"; // Mysql username
$password="bonjour3"; // Mysql password
$db_name="itit"; // Database name
$tbl_name="members"; // Table name

// Connect to server and select databse.
$mysqli = new mysqli("$host", "$username", "$password", "$db_name")or die("cannot connect");

// Define $myusername and $mypassword
$myusername=$_POST['myusername'];
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword'];

$sql = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username=? and password=?");
$sql->bind_param('ss',$myusername,$mypassword);
$sql->execute();
$sql->store_result();//apply to prepare statement
$numRows = $sql->num_rows;

if($numRows === 1){
    $_SESSION['username'] = $myusername;
}
else {
    echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}

session_destroy();

?>
```

js/application.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#login").submit(function(e) {  
        e.preventDefault();
        $.post("checklogin.php", $(this).serialize(), function(){
            $("#showuser").load("templates/login_success.php");
            $("#login").remove();
        });
    });
});
```

templates/login_success.php

```
<?php
session_start();

if($_SESSION['username'] === null){
    header("location: ../index.php");
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1>Login Successful</h1>
<h2>Username: <? echo $_SESSION['username']?></h2>
<a href = "logout.php">Log out</a>
</body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE**

Here is the source code from after an attempted log in. I will try to show why I think that $_SESSION['username'] is never being set (but why?)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<body>
<div id="showuser">
  <title>it IT</title>
  <script src="reqscripts/jquery.js">
  <script src="js/application.js">
  <form id="login" action="checklogin.php" method="post">
  <h1>Member Login</h1>
    <p>
      Username: <input id="myusername" type="text" name="myusername">
    </p>
    <p>
      Password: <input id="mypassword" type="password" name="mypassword">
    </p>
  <input type="submit" value="Login" name="Submit">
  </form>
  <form id="register" action="checkreglogin.php" method="post">
  <h1>Member Registration</h1>
    <p>
      Username: <input id="rmyusername" type="text" name="rmyusername">
    </p>
    <p>
      Password: <input id="rmypassword" type="password" name="rmypassword">
    </p>
    <p>
      Email: <input id="myemail" type="text" name="myemail">
    </p>
    <input type="submit" value="Register" name="Submit">
  </form>
  <div id="showuser"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Notice how the entire page is in the  division...but there is also and empty "showuser" div at the bottom. This confuses me. I think that, when checklogin.php is called by the form - something goes wrong, and the user never gets saved in $_SESSION['username']. Therefore...when login_success.php gets called - $_SESSION['username'] is set to null...and index.php (all of it) loads on $.post request...because that is what would happen when $_SESSION['username'] is null according to login_success.php. Essentially...login_success.php becomes index.php somewhere along the way. Enlighten me!

Comment: Please check the network tab, is it returning 500 Internal Server error on the ajax response?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy where is the network tab?

Comment: It's in your Firebug, click on 'Network' as a tab. It will show the request you make, it will also show what the server returns.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy dont see any errors only ... `304 Not Modified`, `200 OK`, and `302 Found` ... a few of the requests have the same status.

Comment: The response to the POST is shown after the URL - 200 OK. Subsequent responses are 302, 200,200,200.

Comment: @MikeW indeed...it is shown :)

Comment: after looking at the source of index.php after attempted log in - it appears that index.php is being placed in a "showuser" div by the jquery because when login_success gets called $_SESSION['username'] is null and therefore index.php gets rendered in the showuser div (a little complicated...). There is an empty "showuser" div at the bottom too (odd). I'll post the source with an attempt at what I think is going on.

Comment: um....session_destroy();<-- this destroy the session, you wont get any $_SESSION['username'], put that in the else block

Comment: Also, maybe better to use unset($_SESSION['key']);

Comment: @fattomhk that did it! post your answer so i can give you credit :)

Comment: Cheers, you can answer yourselves with more explanation, it helps you understand it more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, thanks to @fattomhk for the comment. I had to put the session_destroy() line in checklogin.php into the else block...like so:

```
...

else {
    echo "Wrong Username or Password";
    session_destroy();
}
?>
```

The session was getting destroyed after the checklogin.php script ran - thus the session username was never being set...and login_success.php checks for a username before loading the page...if there is no username - it loads index.php (which is why the page wasn't changing upon log in).